# Combine two SELECTS from same table

Tags: mysql

I have an table with projects in them:

- id (int)
- ordering (int)
- content (string)

My projects-page shows the current project and a preview of the next three projects. For fetching the next three projects, I would like to use a clean MySQL query. Of course, if the person is on one of the last projects, there are not 3 more projects left to show.

So it then needs to show the first one again.

Basically Im trying to combine these two statements:

```
SELECT *
FROM projects
WHERE ordering > {currentProjectOrdering}
ORDER BY ordering ASC
```

and

```
SELECT *
FROM projects
WHERE ordering > 0
ORDER BY ordering ASC
```

and also

```
LIMIT 0,3
```

In a nutshell: get the next three records with higher ordering than the current project, if (some of) these do not exist, start from ordering = 1.

Assuming there are 10 projects:
Project 1 shows 2,3 and 4
Project 2 shows 3,4 and 5
...
Project 9 shows 10, 1 and 2

Comment: why not just combine the two where statements?

Comment: Is that `Union` what you want?

Comment: So simple.... combine both where clause in one SELECT...

Comment: it's not as simple as combining the two statement. I only want to use the second statement if the first one returns less than 3 results

Answer (score 2):

If you want data from first condition **AND** second condition use

```
SELECT *
FROM projects
WHERE ordering > {currentProjectOrdering} AND ordering > 0
ORDER BY ordering ASC
LIMIT 0,3
```

If you want data from first condition **OR** second condition use

```
SELECT *
FROM projects
WHERE ordering > {currentProjectOrdering} OR ordering > 0
ORDER BY ordering ASC
LIMIT 0,3
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing this out, unfortunately this is not what I mean:
the OR-statement will get all my results and the AND statement will get all results that have a higher value for 'ordering' than the current project. What I'm trying to achieve is: get the next three records with higher ordering than the current project, if (some of) these do not exist, start from ordering = 1.

Answer (score 0):

Something Like this should work (assuming you limiting by just projects that person is working on):

```
     SELECT * FROM projects WHERE person = person_id && (ordering > 0 && COUNT(id) < 4) 
|| (ordering >= currentProjectOrdering && COUNT(id) >= 4)) ORDER BY ordering LIMIT 0,3;
```

Comment: thanks shawn, but I don't think this statement will get me the results I'm looking for, do you think you could explain you query to me?

Comment: yeah basically it relies on the order of operations to get want you want. So in pseudo code the where statement is: if person == person_id then if ordering greater than 0 and there are less than 4 projects then select those records else if ordering is greater than or equal to the currentProjectOrdering and there 4 or more records for this user return the top 4.

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious about this. I don't have mysql and can't test, but I don't *think* you are going to get the 3 records you want in these examples - if you are at the end of the list and need to grab 1 or 2 from the beginning.  I'm playing with `TSQL` - so there is no `LIMIT` Hence the `TOP`.

I'm also curious if anyone can do it better.

```
SELECT  TOP 3 
    CASE
    WHEN ORDERING >= {currentProjectOrdering} THEN ORDERING
    ELSE {currentProjectOrdering} - ORDERING END AS DISPLAYORDER,*
FROM SO_projects  
WHERE (ordering >= {currentProjectOrdering} AND ordering < {currentProjectOrdering}+ 3 ) OR ordering < 3
ORDER BY DISPLAYORDER DESC
```

Can't promise as I have no idea about MYSQL, but here is my try. In T-SQL `TOP` returns the specified number of recs (3 in this case) depending on the ORDER BY.  There is no equivocation to the 0 in the 0,3 part (I wish) of `LIMIT`. I googled and it looks like the `CASE` stuff should be pretty similar.  You may be able to get rid of the > and < because of how `LIMIT` works.  The logic works on SqlServer:

```
SELECT  
    CASE
    WHEN ORDERING >= {currentProjectOrdering} THEN ORDERING
    ELSE {currentProjectOrdering} - ORDERING END AS DISPLAYORDER,*
FROM SO_projects  
WHERE (ordering >= {currentProjectOrdering} AND ordering < {currentProjectOrdering} + 3    ) OR ordering < 3
ORDER BY DISPLAYORDER DESC 
LIMIT 0,3
```

Comment: seems legit, too bad I have no idea how to write this fr mysql :-( thanks for you time though!